# Linux kernel thread address space

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I read that linux kernel threads don't have their own address space, their mm field is set to NULL. I know that all kernel threads share address space, but still, they have their own stack right? They need to somehow describe that field, and without mm, how to they do that? and other lists like open files, where do they keep it? also, what's the point of setting active_mm field to previous user task's mm? thanks in advance.

Comment: This overlaps question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235897/no-address-space-for-linux-kernel-threads?rq=1

Comment: Some answer to the stack question can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083236/does-there-exist-kernel-stack-for-each-process, albeit the answer lacks any reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As their name suggest, kernel threads work in kernel mode, so its stack is referenced by a CPU register (i.e: `ss`, `ebp`).

Open files references (as any other process) are kept in the process descriptor field `struct files_struct *files`. They have nothing to do with memory descriptors.

For regular process, the fields `mm` and `active_mm` are normally the same. Kernel threads don't own any memory descriptor, so they use the one that was *active* (`active_mm`) of the previously running process, hence, kernel threads `mm` is always null and they use `active_mm`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it really helped but do they use active_mm in any way?

Comment: I can't come with an example right now, they need `active_mm` because they use the last process page table somehow to not override some TLB entries. I can't get into more details about that, sorry :(